# Delphi и БД - Постоянные ошибки

Tags: delphi, база-данных

**Table1: Missing TableName property**

Что за хрень у меня с БД???

Достало уже.

Какой БД не используй - везде аналогичные ошибки!

Всё делаю по инструкциям!
Всего 1 строчка кода -

```
Table1.Active:=true;
```

Свои БД или чужие - вообще нет разницы(

Comment: К.О. в лице появляющегося исключения намекает на то, что надо указать свойство TableName.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableName то укажите в компоненте и алиас или коннекцию (смотря что используете)